# CSS solution for fixing a nav bar below header

Tags: css, position, css-position

Is there a CSS-only way to fix a nav bar (or any element really) below a header, but at the top of the page when scrolling past the header?

I know how to do it with js, I was just curious if there was a clever way to do it with CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't conditionally style elements based on the scroll value of the page, simply because CSS doesn't care, and doesn't measure that parameter. JavaScript however does. So your solution would have to involve JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no fix with pure CSS.

If `:target` would work without clicking any element maybe yes. But I think not.